# winjs: unexpected string is shown automatically, while displays pages?

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

Everything is fine for the below code. But, if i run as per the below code, while showing the output, `[object Object]` is displayed automatically. I don't know why

```
function buttonClick() 
{
var getFile = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
if (getFile < 455 && getFile > 0)
{
    var content = document.getElementById("def-content");
    var output = new WinJS.UI.HtmlControl(content, { uri: '/def/f' + getFile + '.html' });
    content.innerText = output;
 }
 else
 {
 var fails = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Expected Input Range: 1 to 454");
 fails.showAsync();
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't saved the content in var `output`. This will surely works;

```
function buttonClick() 
{
var getFile = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
if (getFile < 455 && getFile > 0)
{
    var content = document.getElementById("def-content");
    var output = new WinJS.UI.HtmlControl(content, { uri: '/def/f' + getFile + '.html' });
    content.innerText = "";        
 }
 else
 {
 var fails = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Expected Input Range: 1 to 454");
 fails.showAsync();
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious because you are assigning instance of object to that content div. So it is calling `toString()` method to that instance. `var output` is not a `String`.

instead of `content.innerText = output;`

use

`WinJS.UI.processAll();`

Comment: if i used this, contents are not changed if other number is given in the textbox. it shows under the first content.

Comment: let me explains you detaily, if i put WinJS.UI.processAll(); instead content.innerText = output; as per my code, i have textbox to gain input from user, if enters 3 it will display f3.html and likewise it will display the html page. while using WinJS.UI.processAll(), if press 3, f3.html is displayed. then if user enters 4, f4.html displayed under f3.html. f3.html doesn't hidden. then user enters 6, f6.html is displayed under f3.html and f4.html. but, while uses innertext, it shows single page in the <div tag>. but [object Object] is displayed –